# Dual boot Windows 8+Ubuntu 18.04 no longer works with Secure Boot enabled

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, broadcom

About three years ago, I managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 side by side with Windows 8 on a Lenovo laptop. Secure Boot was enabled and both OSs worked great.

Some 18 months ago, an update to the Broadcom WiFi driver meant that the required modules would no longer work with Secure Boot on. I searched these forums for a solution that would enable me to continue using Secure Boot - with Secure Boot on, Ubuntu would start up, but I'd have no WiFi.

I have since upgraded to 18.04 hoping that this would solve the problem, but did not have any luck.

As I could not get the WiFi to work again under Secure Boot, so I disabled it in the BIOS.

Now I'd like to get Ubuntu fully functional again with Secure Boot enabled, but I've been seeing a message along the lines of:

*Ubuntu has been blocked by the current security policy* when I boot it up with Secure Boot enabled.

Is there a way to get Ubuntu + WiFi working once again with Secure Boot enabled? Although I have used Linux for a number of years, I am not super confident with advanced commands.

All the best

Edited to clarify that I've since upgraded to 18.04.

Comment: The 14.04 has expired, you need a current version. I have not done it, but new versions require the user to assign his own secure boot key (MOK) to proprietary drivers. Ubuntu cannot provide a key for any proprietary drivers it provides. often easier not to use Secure Boot for now. See method 3. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS More details: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/Testing

Comment: Hi oldfred, thank you for the reply. I should have added that I've since updated to 18.04. Apologies for the confusion.